# how to use libtorrent's udp protocol tracker protocol in python

Tags: python, udp, libtorrent

I have gone through the following link http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html but I am not able to understand which functions we need to call in order to send the data using udp tracker's protocol.

Comment: The link isn't working and I can't seem to find it on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tracker protocol. The client does not need to take any action to use it. You just need to add a torrent which has a udp:// URL in its tracker list. libtorrent will automatically contact trackers, whether they be http or udp.

Comment: Can you point me out some good tutorial links for libtorrent in order to develop torrent client using libtorrent in python.

Comment: The best I can come up with are: http://libtorrent.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libtorrent/trunk/bindings/python/simple_client.py?revision=7783&view=markup and http://libtorrent.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libtorrent/trunk/bindings/python/client.py?revision=7783&view=markup